# Pull data from 1 sheet to another without pulling empty cells as 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 excel sheet that is actively pulling data from a different csv sheet.

Formula:

> =[CEE.xls]Leads!$G$1:$M$100000

The issue I'm running into is it is pulling empty cells and answering as "0"

I'd like empty cells to just be empty in the active sheet.

Comment: Are you pulling text or numbers? If text then add `&""` to the end of what you have provided above; if numbers then for all intents and purposes, you **should** be returning a zero but there are ways around that if you specifically do not want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=IF([CEE.xls]Leads!G1<>"",[CEE.xls]Leads!G1,"")
```

And copy it into the range you need to populate.

Comment: This helped me find the answer:
=IF([CEE.xls]Leads!$A$1<>"",[CEE.xls]Leads!$A$1,"")

Difference is in the above formula you had two "!!" next to each other, and there only needed to be 1. As well, when calling info from a separate sheet you need the "$" in front of the cell you are calling.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @WyattErnst - I updated the answer for the typo with the double exclamation marks.